UTF 8 character printing
I'd like to print characters in UTF 8, for example the ಚ (U+0C9A) character. I have the following program which is supposed to work, yet it either prints out a '?' or nothing at all, depending on the terminal. I tried windows terminal, command prompt and powershell as well. Can you help me?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void utf8()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");

    wchar_t ch = 0x0C9A; 
    wprintf(L"Character for U+0C9A: %lc\n", ch);

}

int main()
{
    
    utf8();
    return 0;
}


Under Linux it works fine. Output is: Character for U+0C9A: ಚ

If Windows, what's your console's code page? (What's the number output by chcp?) You might be restricted to characters in that code page's character set.

This is handled by the terminal emulator, not C.

I've tried using chcp 65001 with which it should work fine, but the result is the same...(nothing)

Is that a valid locale on Windows?

Yes, I guess...

Although Winows console has code page 65001, it has a limited character set, those it does not know are output as ?.

wprintf is not a function to print utf8.

@Moldovan Sanyi, What was the return value of setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8")?

Your program works perfectly under Windows and correctly outputs the unicode character U+0C9A. The locale is just ignored and your setlocale line has no effect on the Windows system.
The problem is that the console has still some MS/DOS inheritance and it can display only a reduced set of characters. The chcp 65001 asks the console to decode UTF8 encoding to find the character to display, but does not make it magically able to display the whole range of unicode characters.
I have tried your code without any change under the MSYS2 console and got as expected
Character for U+0C9A: ಚ

BTW as you are using wprintf no UTF8 conversion has ever occurred: the program has directly given to the MSYS2 console a 16 bits character, and the console has directly displayed it...

Write them as UTF-8 sequences.  They will be interpreted as bytes by the compiler (or the implementation of the printing routine) and will be output as UTF on a utf-8 configured terminal.
